# How do I handle image sizing in hero area?

Tags: html, css, image-size

I have created a hero area and between this, I have created two divisions and applied a style display with the grid. Now I have put text and buttons on one side and the other side contains an image. As per the Figma file, I need to set the image a little bit bigger than the text area in the same portion of the display. Please help me to code this properly.
I have coded this,

```
**HTML Part**

    <section class="hero-area">
        <div class="hero-text child">
            <div class="text-area">
                <h1 class="text-transform">Create Stunning <br>
                Email Campaigns</h1>
                <p>Create and launch email campaigns that captivate <br>
                your customers in just a few clicks.</p>
                <button class="button button-1">Try Now</button>
                <button class="button button-2">Get A Demo</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="hero-img child">
            <img class="image-size" src="./images/banner-photo.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
</section>

**CSS Part**

.hero-area {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  margin: 25px 0px;
  padding: 25px 5px;
}

.hero-text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.image-size {
    width: 130%;
    height: auto;
}

.text-area h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-weight: 700;
  margin: 0;
}
```